# ros python publisher/subscriber

Tags: python, ros, rospy

I am trying to subscribe to a 4 different publishers in ROS through python. I use the following code :

```
def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo (" Publisher1 Value %s ", custom_msg1.custom_string1)
    rospy.loginfo (" Publisher2 Value %s ", custom_msg2.custom_string2)
    rospy.loginfo (" Publisher3 Value %s ", custom_msg3.custom_string3)
    rospy.loginfo (" Publisher4 Value %s ", custom_msg4.custom_string4)
    rospy.loginfo (" float_publisher value %f ", data.Float64)

def python_code():
    rospy.init_node("python_code")
    rospy.Subscriber("float_publisher",Float64,callback)
    rospy.Subscriber("publisher1", custom_msg1,callback)
    rospy.Subscriber("publisher2", custom_msg2,callback)
    rospy.Subscriber("publisher3", custom_msg3,callback)
    rospy.Subscriber("publisher4", custom_msg4,callback)
    rospy.loginfo(" Test: start spinning!")
    rospy.spin()
    rospy.loginfo("node has shutdown!")
```

where **custom_msg1.msg** contains **custom_string1** defined as string and in the same way **custom_msg2.msg**, **custom_msg3.msg** and **custom_msg4.msg**

I want know whether I have used the **float** message and also the **custom messages** correctly. 
Output is as follows:

```
Publisher1 Value <member 'custom_string1' of 'custom_msg1' objects>
Publisher2 Value <member 'custom_string2' of 'custom_msg2' objects>
Publisher3 Value <member 'custom_string3' of 'custom_msg3' objects>
Publisher4 Value <member 'custom_string4' of 'custom_msg4' objects>
```

Ending with an error:

```
rospy.loginfo (" float_publisher value %f ", data.Float64)
AttributeError: 'Custom_msg4' object has no attribute 'Float64'
```

I don't know what is going wrong here

Comment: @jonrsharpe I get an output, which is wrong and also an error message .

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match the code you posted. Also, note that the last line of `callback` isn't quite like the first four.

Comment: I had changed the code. I used the import function to import the float and missed to update the same in the code which I posted. I will update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to subscribe to five different topics with five different message types the best way to do it is to use five different callback functions, e.g.:

- one for `publisher1` that publishes `custom_msg1`
- `publisher2` that publishes `custom_msg2`
- `publisher3` that publishes `custom_msg3`
- `publisher4` that publishes `custom_msg4`
- and one for `float_publisher` that publishes `float64` messages.

In the call back function the parameter data is basically a structure that has all of the components that are declared in the message header. The error that you are getting is because the call back function is being called with data of type `custom_msg4` and it is looking for a component called `Float64` in it.

```
def callback1(data):
    rospy.loginfo (" Publisher1 Value %s ", data.custom_string1)

def callback2(data):
    rospy.loginfo (" Publisher2 Value %s ", data.custom_string2)
    
def callback3(data):
    rospy.loginfo (" Publisher3 Value %s ", data.custom_string3)

def callback4(data):
    rospy.loginfo (" Publisher4 Value %s ", data.custom_string4)

def callback5(data):
    rospy.loginfo (" float_publisher value %f ", data.Float64)

def python_code():
    rospy.init_node("python_code")
    rospy.Subscriber("float_publisher",Float64,callback5)
    rospy.Subscriber("publisher1", custom_msg1,callback1)
    rospy.Subscriber("publisher2", custom_msg2,callback2)
    rospy.Subscriber("publisher3", custom_msg3,callback3)
    rospy.Subscriber("publisher4", custom_msg4,callback4)
    rospy.loginfo(" Test: start spinning!")
    rospy.spin()
    rospy.loginfo("node has shutdown!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use one function you will have to use an if else to

distinguish between the different subscribers.

```
def callback(data,who):
    if who == 5:
      rospy.loginfo (" float_publisher value %f ", data.data)
    else:
      rospy.loginfo (" Publisher%d Value %s ",who, data.data)


def python_code():
    rospy.init_node("python_code")
    rospy.Subscriber("float_publisher",Float64,callback,5)
    rospy.Subscriber("publisher1", String,callback,1)
    rospy.Subscriber("publisher2", String,callback,2)
    rospy.Subscriber("publisher3", String,callback,3)
    rospy.Subscriber("publisher4", String,callback,4)
    rospy.loginfo(" Test: start spinning!")
    rospy.spin()
    rospy.loginfo("node has shutdown!")
```